# Check if LDAP server is online

Tags: linux, ldap, server

I need to check if our network LDAP server is online and I've found ***ldapsearch*** command could be suitable for our task.
I'd like to use it without 'username', because I'm not sure to know any username from our database.

It's possible to check only 'online' status for LDAP server?

Comment: LAPD → Los Angeles Police Department?

Answer (score 0):

Some servers will not allow anonymous authentication. Something like

```
ldapsearch -p 389 -h server.example.com -b "" -s base 'objectclass=*'
```

Would be your best bet. This ASSUMES port 389.

-jim